# What is the standard EOS.IO development environment (IDE, OS, etc)?

Tags: nodeos

I'm just wondering if there is a developer-friendly development environment for EOS.IO (https://github.com/EOSIO/eos) ?
Because I found using a editor is not convenient enough to do some unit testing.

Comment: This link will also help. https://infinitexlabs.com/setup-ide-for-eos-development/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) which is not free, but I found it very useful. You can use any other C++ IDE like [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

The important part is that EOSIO is using [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to build the project (it's like Maven / Gradle for Java or npm for Node.js) which should be integrated in most of the IDEs.

In terms of testing I guess you can use actually [eosjs](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs) and assert the results of the contracts using javascript testing frameworks like [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) (as test runner) + [Chai](http://www.chaijs.com/) (as assertion library) or any other libs.

For running EOSIO locally I use Docker on top of my Ubuntu.

To experiment with contract development I actually use official github repository and write the contracts in https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts directory.

Here is very useful video for setup described above: [Building Distributed Apps With EOS.IO Blockchain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3Tx2DseLGE)

Also, check this guide [Manually Install Dependencies](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/overview) in case you want to setup related dependencies which you will need when running and building the project

Comment: For the javascript tests you could use https://github.com/LimeChain/eoslime . Allows to deploy empty contract each time. Also makes using eosjs a bit easier in the testing cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [infeos](https://github.com/infiniteXLabs/infeos). It's a javascript & [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/infeos) framework for developing, building, deploying and testing EOSIO dApps. It works perfectly with VS Code or any other editor. Some of the main key features are:

1. Setup a dev environment in a matter of minutes
2. Start a full local node in seconds with only one command and option to choose your network for development - EOS, Telos or Worbli
3. Develop EOSIO dApps on Windows as easily as on Mac. You can run a local EOS node on Windows :)
4. Unit test your EOSIO smart contracts using JavaScript - you can check also the tutorial I wrote a few days ago: ["Unit test EOS smart contracts with Javascript"](https://medium.com/infinitexlabs/unit-test-eos-smart-contracts-with-javascript-20ea8840b5bc)
5. Full control over your environment configurations and deployment setup
6. Optimized dApp project structure for high-quality and efficiency dApps
7. Super easy and simple to use - you don’t need to be an EOSIO developer to work with the smart contracts of a dApp. All back-ends and front-ends developers now have the power to work with you dApp on blockchain level in just learning a few commands

You can also see it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxhchHmKiDU) in action. :)