# Main steps for preparing IDE for Nodeos development

Tags: nodeos, development

I'm a Java developer so I am a bit new to prepare IDE for C+ project. What are the main steps for preparing development environment for Nodeos?

I downloaded full source code from github/eos/eosio and successful built on my Mac.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/616/what-is-the-standard-eos-io-development-environment-ide-os-etc

Comment: Oh, my question is quite clear, it's what main steps could be done. That link you provide is about the possibility not describe main steps.

Comment: It is not clear which IDE you want to setup.

Comment: eclipse C,C++ or any common one

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial from Kevin Heifner: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3Tx2DseLGE, he talks about setting up your dev environment and CLion in the first 15 minutes of the tutorial.

Comment: It's for dapp development, I am looking for establishing development environment for NODEOS, in another words for EOS core. So that I could to do some experiment like changing inflation rate..ect

Comment: This link will also help. infinitexlabs.com/setup-ide-for-eos-development

Comment: u'd better use Visual Studio Code, as it's much simpler and flexible. Also supports everything you need and more

Answer (score 1):

The official docs [added an article](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/ide-configuration) on configuring IDEs with a section on Eclipse C++ IDE.

Excerpt:

> In the `contracts` folder, in the local EOS repository, create a shortcut / symbolic link of the `eosiolib` folder and place it in the `eclipse-workspace` folder. This is done to give smart contracts access to needed header files.